# Creating Rest Api in python using JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, rest, api

I'm new to python REST API and so facing some particular problems. I want that when I enter the input as pathlabid(primary key), I want the corresponding data assigned with that key as output. When I run the following code i only get the data corresponding to the first row of table in database even when the id i enter belong to some other row.
This is the VIEWS.PY

```
class pathlabAPI(View):
@csrf_exempt
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # dont worry about the CSRF here
    return super(pathlabAPI, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request):
    post_data = json.loads(request.body)
    Pathlabid = post_data.get('Pathlabid') or ''
    lablist = []
    labdict = {}

    lab = pathlab()
    labs = lab.apply_filter(Pathlabid = Pathlabid)


    if Pathlabid :


        for p in labs:
                labdict["Pathlabid"] = p.Pathlabid
                labdict["name"] = p.Name
                labdict["email_id"] = p.Emailid
                labdict["contact_no"] = p.BasicContact
                labdict["alternate_contact_no"] = p.AlternateContact
                labdict["bank_account_number"] = p.Accountnumber
                labdict["ifsccode"] = p.IFSCcode
                labdict["country"] = p.Country
                labdict["homepickup"] = p.Homepickup
                lablist.append(labdict)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(lablist))
    else:

        for p in labs:
                labdict["bank_account_number"] = p.Accountnumber
                lablist.append(labdict)
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(lablist))
```

Comment: Your life will be much more easier if you use Djnago Rest Framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with the overall approach and code but to fix the issue you're describing, but as a first fix I agree with the other answer: you need to take the `return` statement out of the loop. Right now you're `return`ing your list as soon as you step through the loop one time, which is why you always get a list with one element. Here's a fix for that (you will need to add `from django.http import JsonResponse` at the top of your code):

```
if Pathlabid:
    for p in labs:
        labdict["Pathlabid"] = p.Pathlabid
        labdict["name"] = p.Name
        labdict["email_id"] = p.Emailid
        labdict["contact_no"] = p.BasicContact
        labdict["alternate_contact_no"] = p.AlternateContact
        labdict["bank_account_number"] = p.Accountnumber
        labdict["ifsccode"] = p.IFSCcode
        labdict["country"] = p.Country
        labdict["homepickup"] = p.Homepickup
        lablist.append(labdict)
else:
    for p in labs:
        labdict["bank_account_number"] = p.Accountnumber
        lablist.append(labdict)

return JsonResponse(json.dumps(lablist))
```

As suggested in the comments, using Django Rest Framework or a similar package would be an improvement. As a general rule, in Django or other ORMs, you want to avoid looping over a queryset like this and adjusting each element. Why not serialize the queryset itself and do the logic that's in this loop in your template or other consumer?

Comment: Now I'm using Django Rest Framework, I want to retrieve data to some corresponding id . Is it not possible to check the same in google rest client. "chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html" . By passing the id in the request body. I'm using the GET method and passing the id as {"Pathlabid" : 1} but in response body I'm getting the complete list of data containing all the entries not just the single entry corresponding to the id=1 which i want.

Comment: You could do things this way by inspecting the `kwargs` argument to the `list` method assuming you've properly set up a serializer and viewset but it seems like what you want to do is leverage the `get` method on the viewset so rather than passing a querystring you'd just append `/1/` to your url. But that's a different question beyond the scope of this. I'd suggest [working all the way through the tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#serializers) to get the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You are return the response in for loop so that loop break on 1st entry

```
import json
some_list = []
for i in data:
    some_list.append({"key": "value"})
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"some_list": some_list}), content_type="application/json")
```

Try above example to solve your problem

Comment: The result is the same. Its giving me the same output even after i change the Id.